# Ruby On Rails - Group by, multilevel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, multidimensional-array

I have a user model. I want to bring statistics on each month that there has been sign ups and in these months I want the users to be grouped by their age.

```
Created_at
--> age
```

I thought this would do it, but the second grouping never gets done.

```
@user_ages = User.all
@user_ages = @user_ages.group_by{|t| t.created_at.month}
@user_ages.each do | usr |
  usr[1] = usr[1].group_by{|u| u.age_id}
end
```

Age is its own model, therefor I want it to be grouped by the age_id the user model have.

Comment: It is done, But to see it you need to use `#map` method. Not `#each`. `each` return the object, on which you called it, doesn't care what work you did inside the block.

Comment: @ArupRakshit
user_ages.map {|usr| usr[1] = usr[1].group_by{|u| u.age_id} } don't do it though?

Comment: Got your point..Use `map!`. But it is your own risk. Because it will modify the orginal object.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - map! is not possible.. undefined method `map!' for #<Hash:0x007fa7c6346348>